# Unable to import json into mongo db atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm attempting to import json into an atlas db.
The attempt uses this code:

```
mongoimport --uri "mongodb://usr:pass@myurlname.uia8q.mongodb.net/paintura?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --collection products --file pathtojson
```

all parameters in the above are correct via the connect docs.

exact error is:

```
error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: myurlname.uia8q.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp: lookup paintura.uia8q.mongodb.net: no such host }, ] }
```

For the user I have atlas admin selected so I assume it should have full privelege.
I also have cleared my ip in the ip list.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: How do you connect normally? Perhaps you missed the authentication source in your connection URI

Comment: Ok that's what it was I was missing: mongodb+srv: @WernfriedDomscheit want to add it as answer?